# Regarding helper method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
def admin_options_for_registrar(registrar)
  if registrar.enrollment_application != nil && registrar.enrollment_application.status == "Complete"
    ["Show", "/registrars/"+registrar.id.to_s],["Edit", "/edit_registrars/"+registrar.id.to_s], ["Dashboard", "/homes/"+registrar.enrollment_application.id.to_s], ]
  else
    ["Show", "/registrars/"+registrar.id.to_s],["Edit", "/edit_registrars/"+registrar.id.to_s], ["Dashboard", "/homes/"+registrar.enrollment_application.id.to_s], ] 
  end
end
```

This helper method I wrote in model file
Now I am calling this method in view file this way

```
<% if xyx!= nil? %>
<td><%= select_tag "options", options_for_select([admin_option_for_registrar])
<% end %>
```

and this should give me the drop down with Edit, Show and Dashboard but it gives me error undefined mentod ' admin_options_for_registrar'

Any help??

Answer (score 1):

Helper methods should go in a helper file in 'app/helpers', not in the model file.

As written, it sounds like you've created an instance method for your model, which you're trying to invoke without an instance.

**Update**

There are numerous other problems with the function itself:

- seems you have a syntax error in your function, there are extra  `]`'s on both branches of your if
- both branches of your if are identical; why have an if at all?
- your function isn't returning anything; you need the `return` keyword
- your function takes an argument (`registrar`) but you're not passing one in
- your enclosing the result of the function in an addtional array by calling it withing `[]`

Try to get the following working, and then add the branching logic back in:

```
def admin_options_for_registrar(registrar)
    [ 
        ["Show", "/registrars/"+registrar.id.to_s],
        ["Edit", "/edit_registrars/"+registrar.id.to_s],
        ["Dashboard", "/homes/"+registrar.enrollment_application.id.to_s]
    ]
end


# pass the registrar object into your function
<%= select_tag "options", options_for_select(admin_option_for_registrar(registrar))
```

Comment: I moved in to helper file but now instead of showing drop down it just shows me "option_for_registrar" in drop down instead of options like edit, show and dashboard